# Unescape Python Strings From HTTP

Tags: python, http, header, urllib2, mod-wsgi

I've got a string from an HTTP header, but it's been escaped..  what function can I use to unescape it?

```
myemail%40gmail.com -> myemail@gmail.com
```

Would urllib.unquote() be the way to go?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I am pretty sure that urllib's [`unquote`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote) is the common way of doing this.

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.unquote("myemail%40gmail.com")
'myemail@gmail.com'
```

There's also [`unquote_plus`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote_plus):

> Like unquote(), but also replaces plus signs by spaces, as required for unquoting HTML form values.

Comment: K, just wanted to make sure.. I hate using a function that appears to do the job, but ends up only working with a few examples that I did and breaking with real world vars. heh.

Then it becomes impossible to track down the problem.. :P

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3, these functions are [`urllib.parse.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote) and [`urllib.parse.unquote_plus`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote).

The latter is used for example for query strings in the HTTP URLs, where the space characters () are traditionally encoded as plus character (`+`), and the `+` is percent-encoded to `%2B`.

In addition to these there is the [`unquote_to_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote_to_bytes) that converts the given encoded string to `bytes`, which can be used when the encoding is not known or the encoded data is binary data. However there is no `unquote_plus_to_bytes`, if you need it, you can do:

```
def unquote_plus_to_bytes(s):
    if isinstance(s, bytes):
        s = s.replace(b'+', b' ')
    else:
        s = s.replace('+', ' ')
    return unquote_to_bytes(s)
```

---

More information on whether to use `unquote` or `unquote_plus` is available at [URL encoding the space character: + or %20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it appears that [`urllib.unquote()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote) accomplishes that task. (I [tested it against your example on codepad](http://codepad.org/SerdBuAK).)