# URL encoding the space character: + or %20?

Tags: url, url-encoding

When is a space in a URL encoded to `+`, and when is it encoded to `%20`?

Answer (score 525, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding) (emphasis and link added):

> When data that has been entered into HTML forms is submitted, the form field names and values are encoded and sent to the server in an HTTP request message using method GET or POST, or, historically, via email. **The encoding used by default is based on a very early version of the general URI percent-encoding rules, with a [number of modifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) such as newline normalization and replacing spaces with "+" instead of "%20".** The MIME type of data encoded this way is application/x-www-form-urlencoded, and it is currently defined (still in a very outdated manner) in the HTML and XForms specifications.

So, the *real* percent encoding uses `%20` while form data in URLs is in a modified form that uses `+`. So you're most likely to only see `+` in URLs in the query string after an `?`.

Comment: So + encoding would technically be multipart/form-data encoding, while percent encoding is application/x-www-form-urlencoded?

Comment: @BC: no - `multipart/form-data` uses MIME encoding; `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` uses `+` and properly encoded URIs use `%20`.

Comment: "So you're most likely to only see + in URLs in the query string after an ?" Is an understatement. You should never see "+" in the path part of the URL because it will not do what you expect (space).

Comment: @McDowell your response the comment from BC was very helpful to me, along with the input from Adam Gent

Comment: Hi, I am confused too, sometime I saw the book use "+" but sometime "%20",  When user submit the form, how the form encode the space ? with which character? Is the result browser-dependent?

Comment: So basically: Target of GET submission is `http://www.bing.com/search?q=hello+world` and a resource with space in the name `http://camera.phor.net/cameralife/folders/2012/2012-06%20Pool%20party/`

Comment: [Data uris](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2397.txt) use the same encoding as a [uris](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt). After reading that RFC I can confidently say I'm not smart enough to decipher whether encoding of a space should be allowed as a + character. I can, however, say that if you use + instead of %20 the data uri won't work in browsers.

Comment: @Rob: It probably isn't allowed in data URIs, indeed. Because as stated, itś only in the query part where the `+` is used.

Comment: Note that for email links, you do need %20 and not + after the ?. For example, `mailto:support@example.org?subject=I%20need%20help`. If you tried that with +, the email will open with +es instead of spaces.

Comment: This helped me, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572718/php-convert-spaces-in-string-into-20

Comment: The problem with using plus is that if you want to accept plus signs distinctly from spaces such as ?search=The A+ School

Answer (score 421):

This confusion is because URLs are still 'broken' to this day.

From [a blog post](https://blog.lunatech.com/posts/2009-02-03-what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding):

> Take "http://www.google.com" for instance. This is a URL. A URL is a Uniform Resource Locator and is really a pointer to a web page (in most cases). URLs actually have a very well-defined structure since the first specification in 1994.
>
> We can extract detailed information about the "http://www.google.com" URL:
>
> ```
> +---------------+-------------------+
> |      Part     |      Data         |
> +---------------+-------------------+
> |  Scheme       | http              |
> |  Host         | www.google.com    |
> +---------------+-------------------+
> ```
>
> If we look at a more complex URL such as:
>
> "https://bob:bobby@www.lunatech.com:8080/file;p=1?q=2#third"
>
> we can extract the following information:
>
> ```
> +-------------------+---------------------+
> |        Part       |       Data          |
> +-------------------+---------------------+
> |  Scheme           | https               |
> |  User             | bob                 |
> |  Password         | bobby               |
> |  Host             | www.lunatech.com    |
> |  Port             | 8080                |
> |  Path             | /file;p=1           |
> |  Path parameter   | p=1                 |
> |  Query            | q=2                 |
> |  Fragment         | third               |
> +-------------------+---------------------+
>
> https://bob:bobby@www.lunatech.com:8080/file;p=1?q=2#third
> \___/   \_/ \___/ \______________/ \__/\_______/ \_/ \___/
>   |      |    |          |          |      | \_/  |    |
> Scheme User Password    Host       Port  Path |   | Fragment
>         \_____________________________/       | Query
>                        |               Path parameter
>                    Authority
> ```
>
> The reserved characters are different for each part.
>
> For HTTP URLs, a space in a path fragment part has to be encoded to "%20" (not, absolutely not "+"), while the "+" character in the path fragment part can be left unencoded.
>
> Now in the query part, spaces may be encoded to either "+" (for backwards compatibility: do not try to search for it in the URI standard) or "%20" while the "+" character (as a result of this ambiguity) has to be escaped to "%2B".
>
> This means that the "blue+light blue" string has to be encoded differently in the path and query parts:
>
> "http://example.com/blue+light%20blue?blue%2Blight+blue".
>
> From there you can deduce that encoding a fully constructed URL is impossible without a syntactical awareness of the URL structure.

This boils down to:

**You should have `%20` before the `?` and `+` after.**

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20151218094722/http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding)

Comment: >> you should have %20 before the ? and + after

Sorry for the silly question. I know a bit somehow that hashtag parameter is used after "?" question mark parameter.  Though it is somehow different because using "#" does not reload the page.  But I've been trying to use %20 and + sign after the "#" hashtag, and it seems not working. Which one needs to be used after "#"?

Comment: @Philcyb You might wanna read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: Does the query part actually have an "official" standard? I thought basically that part is application specific. 99.99% of apps use `key1=value1&key1=value2` where keys and values are encoded with whatever rules `encodeURIComponent` follow but AFAIK the contents of the query part is entirely 100% up to the app. Other then it only goes to the first `#` there's no official encoding.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the confusing inconsistency is due to legacy broken design.

Comment: Actually, I just took a look at the LunaTech blog article, which you kindly referenced, and the take-home message seems to be more like: **You must use %20 and not + before the `?`, but after the `?` it is simply a matter of taste**. For the love of God, people, just always use the percent sign-based encoding and clear out some brain space for more important stuff.

Comment: Wow man. I have to say that graph in ASCII looks cool.

Comment: URLs are not "broken". Besides URL decoding it's up to you how you interpret the query string. If you want to interpret `+` as space that's fine, the URL standard doesn't care.

Comment: The conclusion is short and clear, for non-English reader it helps a lot!

Comment: Not sure the blog is fully correct. It states that `/` is valid in `query` but both rfc2396 and rfc1738 show it as a reserved character.

Answer (score 30):

A space may only be encoded to "+" in the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content-type key-value pairs query part of an URL. In my opinion, this is a *may*, not a *must*. In the rest of URLs, it is encoded as %20.

In my opinion, it's better to always encode spaces as %20, not as "+", even in the query part of an URL, because it is the HTML specification ([RFC 1866](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866)) that specified that space characters should be encoded as "+" in "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content-type key-value pairs (see paragraph 8.2.1. subparagraph 1.)

This way of encoding form data is also given in later HTML specifications. For example, look for relevant paragraphs about application/x-www-form-urlencoded in HTML 4.01 Specification, and so on.

Here is a sample string in a URL where the HTML specification allows encoding spaces as pluses: "http://example.com/over/there?name=foo+bar". So, **only after "?", spaces can be replaced by pluses**. In other cases, spaces should be encoded to %20. But since it's hard to determine the context correctly, it's the best practice to never encode spaces as "+".

I would recommend to percent-encode all character except "unreserved" defined in [RFC 3986](http://ttps://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), p.2.3

```
unreserved = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
```

The implementation depends on the programming language that you chose.

If your URL contains national characters, first encode them to UTF-8 and then percent-encode the result.

Comment: Why should anyone care about HTML specification if the requested resource isn't HTML? I've seen "+" in some Web APIs which don't respond with HTML e.g. you request a pdf. I consider it wrong that they dont use "%20".

Comment: @TheincredibleJan, I agree with you. That's what my reply is about.

Comment: @MaximMasiutin When your answer says "This is a MAY, not a MUST", which spec are you referring to? I'm struggling to find a spec that has it as a may. In https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1 using '+' (in the query section) is within a 'must' section of the spec.

Comment: @JosephH - thank you for your note. It is my persional opinion about MAY. I have edited the post. What I meant is that HTML specification you qouted defines "+", but in the URL context, other rules apply, which permit encoding spaces as %20 also.

Comment: Agree!  decodeURIComponent('+')  returns +. So if a space is encoded into +, the server cannot decode it into space.

Answer (score 27):

I would recommend `%20`.

Are you hard-coding them?

This is not very consistent across languages, though.
If I'm not mistaken, in PHP `urlencode()` treats spaces as `+` whereas Python's `urlencode()` treats them as `%20`.

EDIT:

It seems I'm mistaken. Python's `urlencode()` (at least in 2.7.2) uses `quote_plus()` instead of `quote()` and thus encodes spaces as "+".
It seems also that the W3C recommendation is the "+" as per here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1

And in fact, you can follow this interesting debate on Python's own issue tracker about what to use to encode spaces: http://bugs.python.org/issue13866.

EDIT #2:

I understand that the most common way of encoding " " is as "+", but just a note, it may be just me, but I find this a bit confusing:

```
import urllib
print(urllib.urlencode({' ' : '+ '})

>>> '+=%2B+'
```

Comment: Not hardcoding. Trying to determine from an aesthetic perspective what my urls containing spaces will look like.

Comment: Hi, I am confused too, When user submit the html form, how the form encode the space ? with which character? Is the result browser-dependent?

Comment: And the `URLEncoder.encode()` method in Java converts it in `+` as well.

Comment: And then the question arises as to how to treat encoding in the body of a POST request: "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" where the parameters are in the form of "a=b&c=d", but aren't in a URL at all, just the body of the "document." They made a real mess out of this issue, and it's darned difficult to find definitive answers.

Comment: Perls uri_escape() treats them as %20

Comment: A problem with %20 is if you add it to a url then your server redirects that to a new url with the same query, it might encode the percent and you end up with %2520 instead of %20

Comment: In Python 3, the method urllib.parse.urlencode has a parameter called quote_via, that accepts a function. 
Its default value is urllib.parse.quote_plus, but it's possible to choose another function.  So, we can use urllib.parse.quote, and thus encodes spaces as "%20".

Answer (score 17):

To summarize the (somewhat conflicting) answers here, I think it can be boiled down to:

```
| standard      | +   | %20 |
|---------------+-----+-----|
| URL           | no  | yes |
| query string  | yes | yes |
| form params   | yes | no  |
| mailto query  | no  | yes |
```

So historically I think what happened is:

1. The RFC specified a pretty clear standard about the form of URLs and how they are encoded. In this context the query is just a "string", there is no specification how key/value pairs should be encoded
2. The HTTP guys put out a standard of how key/value pairs are to be encoded in form params, and borrowed from the URL encoding standard, except that spaces should be encoded as `+`.
3. The web guys said: cool we have a way to encode key/value pairs let's put that into the URL query string

Result: We end up with two different ways how to encode spaces in a URL depending on which part you're talking about. But it doesn't even violate the URL standard. From URL perspective the "query" is just a blackbox. If you want to use other encodings there besides percent encoding: knock yourself out.

But as the email example shows it can be problematic to borrow from the form-params implementation for an URL query string. So ultimately using %20 is safer but there might not be out of the box library support for it.

Comment: Amazing answer, thanks, but this part was vague, would you explain what example you're talking about? "_as the email example shows it can be problematic to borrow from the form-params implementation for an URL query string._"

Comment: @aderchox I'm referring to this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20/72833702?noredirect=1#comment45499743_1634293. Basically, e-mail clients don't accept the + encoding in general. Thanks for your praise, but I'm not happy with my answer, since it contains some inaccuracies. It wasn't the "HTTP guys" who introduced the + encoding, but the HTML guys (see the HTML <form> tag spec). I plan to fix my answer and provide some references soon.

Answer (score 0):

As I was surprised that nobody did cite the actual [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1) on "percent encoding", I'm adding my own answer here:

As the aforementioned RFC does not include any reference of encoding spaces as `+`, I guess using `%20` is the way to go today.

> For example, "%20" is the percent-encoding for the binary octet "00100000" (ABNF: %x20), which in US-ASCII corresponds to the space character (SP).