# PHP: convert spaces in string into %20?

Tags: php, string, urlencode

How can I convert spaces in string into `%20`?

Here is my attempt:

```
$str = "What happens here?";
echo urlencode($str);
```

The output is `"What+happens+here%3F"`, so the spaces are not represented as `%20`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 259, accepted):

Use the `rawurlencode` function instead.

Comment: Beware if you use this for url (not its query part), converted slashed will cause the url not to work. So if you just need to take care of spaces (maybe for that URL), I suggest str_replace.

Answer (score 32):

The plus sign is the historic encoding for a space character in URL parameters, as [documented in the help](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) for the `urlencode()` function.

That same page contains the answer you need - use `rawurlencode()` instead to get [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) compatible encoding.

Answer (score 28):

I believe that, if you need to use the `%20` variant, you could perhaps use [`rawurlencode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php).