# My function didn't work when I add space PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am not good with PHP I am just trying a few things.
I have a problem with my search function.
If I search for just the first name the search works, instead of when I add space all breaks.

I saw if I add in the URL between the first and the last name a  _  all works.
I need something simple to use for my code to replace the "space" between 2 words to _

here my code

```
if(isset($_GET["search"])) {
    $filtro = " and nome like '%".$_GET["search"]."%'";

}
```

I added this manual
[image]

but the only thing that works now is if I only search for serach=alice

Thanks in advance

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements with placeholder values** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](https://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: Spaces don't belong in URLs. Any arguments like `search` *must* be [URI encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), like `alice%20in%20wonderland`.

Comment: `alice+me` might also work...

Comment: see: [PHP: convert spaces in string into %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572718/php-convert-spaces-in-string-into-20)

Comment: Check php parse_str https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php