# Difference between "+" and "%A0" - urlencoding?

Tags: html, forms, urlencode

I am url encoding a string of text to pass along to a function.  However, it encodes the second space in a double-space as "%A0".  This means that when I decode the string, the "%A0" is displayed as a question mark in a black box.

I really just need to be able to remove the extra space, but I'd like to understand what is causing this and how to handle it correctly.

For example:

```
Something  Something else
```

Encodes to:

```
Something+%A0Something+else
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL encoding the space character: + or %20?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20)

Comment: @AJ: This is not the same. Please read the question. The OP wants to know why `%A0` is appearing in the encoded values, not whether to use `+` or `%20` to escape spaces.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`%A0` indicates a NBSP (U+00A0). `+` indicates a normal space (U+0020). The NBSP displays as a replacement character (U+FFFD) because the encoding of the character does not match the encoding of the page, so its byte sequence is not valid for the page.

Answer (score 4):

A quick Googling shows that `%A0` is the non-breaking space character or `&nbsp;` in html. A `+` is the form-encoding for a standard space character.

[Source](http://sapphiresolutionsltd.com/2011/01/26/html-code-ascii-special-characters-hex-a0-af/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that the second "space" is not really a space, it's a character that that font doesn't have a glyph (I think that's the term) to represent (hence the black box with the question mark). `%A0` is the [escape code](http://www.rolbe.com/2009/03/06/url-escape-codes/) for that character. Your code is technically handling it correctly, I think the problem is with whatever is generating the string in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If I refer to the [chart on this page](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp), %A0 is not a space. %20 is the space caracter's encoded value.