# PHP trim() can't remove whitespaces

Tags: php, trim

I have a problem with trim() function in PHP. I have some text code with whitespaces. This code contain only spaces.

When I use trim in that way:

```
$text = trim($v);
var_dump($text);
```

I got:

> string(2) " "

When I use urlencode to check what is incorect:

```
$text = trim(urlencode($v));
var_dump($text);exit;
```

I got:

> string(6) "%C2%A0"

Why trim() can't remove this whitespace? How I can create my own trim() function to remove these whitespaces?

Thanks.

Comment: `%C2` isn't whitespace...

Comment: you can use str_replace php function

Comment: @Cid [It appears so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6192832/2453432)

Answer (score 2):

`trim()` does not remove "all whitespace characters" from the ends of your string, but only a limited number of fixed characters:

> " " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.
>
> "\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
>
> "\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
>
> "\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return.
>
> "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
>
> "\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.
>
> <sub>https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php</sub>

Your characters might be rendered as whitespace. However, they are not included in this list and are, hence, not removed.

---

You can pass a second parameter to `trim()` to specify the list of characters you want to have removed:

> **character_mask**
>
> Optionally, the stripped characters can also be specified using the character_mask parameter. Simply list all characters that you want to be stripped. With .. you can specify a range of characters.
>
> <sub>https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php</sub>

Comment: OK, I understand. How I can create my own function to remove this whitespace? Can you help me?

Comment: @PavelK In the second parameter to `trim()` you can list all the characters you want to have removed. So add everything that can appear there and you should be fine.

Comment: I see that in documentation but I need convert my "whitespaces" into ASCII. When I try it using iconv, I get `iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string`. How I can convert these whitespaces to ASCII?

Comment: I get the feeling this is not a technical issue, but maybe your current approach can be improved (*Why* do you need to convert *what* to ASCII?). Maybe this should better be discussed in a separate question.

Comment: `Why do you need to convert what to ASCII?` - because I want set this ASCII code as second parameter into trim() function.

Comment: @PavelK - You already have the url codes for them, so you should be able to do: `trim($string, urldecode('%C2%A0') . 'more-chars-if-needed')`.

Answer (score 1):

U can with [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$str=' hello.     ';

$newStr=str_replace(' ','',$str);
```

Check code

```
echo strlen($newStr); //output 6
```