# Hotmail messing with encoded URL parameters

Tags: email, url-encoding, hotmail

We have a system that sends out regular emails with links in, many of which contain URL encoded parameters such as this:

```
href="http://www.mydomain.com/login.aspx?returnurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com%2Fview.aspx%3Fid%3D1234%26alert%3Dtrue"
```

You can see that the "returnurl" parameter is encoded. However, it seems that a large number of our users (seemingly hotmail) are receiving the emails with this paramater *partly* decoded such as:

```
href="http://www.mydomain.com/login.aspx?returnurl=http://www.mydomain.com/view.aspx?view.aspx%3Fid%3D1234%26alert%3Dtrue"
```

Why would it decode like this? Why only partly decode?? I therefore have no idea how to deal with it. I thought of base-64 encoding but that base64 strings contain characters that would need decoding too... I thought of double encoding but then I will not know whether to double-decode the parameter or not... Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: We also se this isse with hotmail users. links works fine in gmail etc. Anyone?

Comment: Sure. Login to a Hotmail account, Create a new email with links just like the original and send it to yourself. Now view message source and find how Hotmail is formatting this message.

Answer (score 0):

One reason this could be happening is because url rules for encoding [are different before and after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20/29948396#29948396) `?` so if mechanism that is doing decoding does it from the 'back' of url and apples query decoding rules until it finds first `?` then this could cause problem you are describing...

Not sure how to deal with it though as I understand system that does this inappropriate decoding is outside of your control. I would try to hide the `?` in return url query somehow...

Comment: How about encoding everything after `returnurl=` to base64? Then decode and forward to decoded path on server side? You could skip standard URL encoding entirely. I see quite a few sites doing this.