# Embedded Url Links in Hotmail

Tags: special-characters, url-encoding, hotmail, email-client

Hotmail auto-encodes embedded url links. It changes '!' to '%21' and thus it makes impossible for a customer who receives an email to follow the actual link.

All other email clients render the correct url but hotmail makes a mess of it..

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8007633/1178314 , isn't it?
But no answers there either.