# Plus sign in query string for ASP.NET site

Tags: c#, special-characters, request.querystring

I few years ago I created a database driven ASP.NET site, which uses a single APSX page to display all site pages. So all the URLs of the site are in the following format:

```
/main.aspx?page=Page+Title+One

/main.aspx?page=Another+Article+Title

/main.aspx?page=Third+Page
```

The main.aspx page gets the query string data (Page+Title+One for example) and uses it as a key to pull the appropriate article content from the SQL server database. The actual title of the page is stored in the db with spaces instead of pluses (for example "Page Title One").

The poor decision to go with the + sign as a word separator in the URL query string is causing lots of issues with search engines lately (duplicate content, etc.), so I want to fix it, but without changing URLs.

What I want to do is when search engine or visitor tries to visit the wrong URL missing the + signs and having white spaces instead, for example:

```
/main.aspx?page=Page Title One
```

I want to do 301 permanent redirect to:

```
/main.aspx?page=Page+Title+One
```

To be able to do this I need to check if the query string value has pluses or white spaces, however when I get the value with Request.QueryString["page"] even if the actual quesry string has pluses in it I still get string with white spaces "Page Title One".

The site runs on IIS6/Win 2003.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, of course you can't put a space in a URI in any case. What you can do is put `%20` in which is the way to encode a space at any point in a URI as well as `+` being the normal way to encode a space in the query portion, and the recommended way to do so in that portion of it because %20 can cause problems.

Because of this is an implementaiton detail application/x-www-form-urlencoded and we normally care about the actual data sent, `Request.QueryString[]` does the unescaping for you, turning both `+` and `%20` into a space.

You want to look at the `Request.RawUrl` (returns a string) or `Request.Url` which returns a `Uri`. Probably the easiest is to feed `Request.Url` into a `UriBuilder` so you can change just the query and get a `Uri` back.

Still, I'd recommend the opposite approach, if you're having issues with duplicate content due to the two possible ways of encoding a space in the query string, go with the recommended norm and turn the cases of `%20` into `+` rather than the other way around.

```
var u = Request.Url;
if(u.Query.Contains("%20"))
{
    var ub = new UriBuilder(u);
    Console.WriteLine(ub.Query);
    string query = ub.Query;
    //note bug in Query property - it includes ? in get and expects it not to be there on set
    ub.Query = ub.Query.Replace("%20", "+").Substring(1);
    Response.StatusCode = 301;
    Response.RedirectLocation = ub.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: My URLs have always used the plus sign only instead of white spaces or the %20, however I see cached pages in Google looking like these 2:  /main.aspx?page=KW1 KW2 and /main.aspx?page=KW1%20KW2, which are both wrong and are causing the duplicate content issues. Now I want to 301 them to the proper URL which is /main.aspx?page=KW1+KW2.

Comment: That's pretty much what I was explaining. Not sure what wasn't clear, so have added code-example which hopefully explains.

Comment: Thanks Jon, this is exactly what I needed :). How do I mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 5):

Using `Request["key"]`, it automatically converts all "+" signs into spaces. You need to use `Request.RawUrl` to see if there are plus signs.

Additionally, you can use `System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` to parse any string query.
You can just test if `Request.QueryString.ToString().Contains("+")` is true, and do logic from there.

Comment: This is exactly my problem. I want to be able to make a distinction between the following 2 GET requests: /main.aspx?page=KW1+KW2 and /main.aspx?page=KW1 KW2.

Comment: See my original post. It seems like `Request.QueryString.ToString().Contains("+")` will give you if it's first or second case.

Comment: Yes, but this won't solve a wrong URL in the following format /main.aspx?page=KW1 KW2+KW3.

Comment: Why? Because you can't `.Replace("+", " ")` the whole string in the end?

Answer (score 3):

The `+` sign is interpreted as a space for URLs.

That is, in order to URL encode a space, you could use `%20` or a `+`.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20) to "URL encoding the space character: + or %20?"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
Request.QueryString["page"].Trim();
```