# Jersey REST service @PathParam decoding

Tags: rest, jersey

I am using Jersey 1.8 with Tomcat 6 to develop the RESTful server.
I have the following service to receive the HTTP request by GET with parameter Input String.

```
@GET
@Path("/searchTest/{inputString}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Override
public Response searchTest(@PathParam("inputString") String inputString) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(inputString);

    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity("OK").build();
}
```

However, if the request parameter included space like : http://localhost:8080/test/service/searchTest/231 2312

The value of the server received is 231%202312

Here mentioned that @PathParam will decode automatically because this not work for me.
[Jax-rs automatic decode pathparam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626990/jax-rs-automatic-decode-pathparam)

Anyone can help?

Comment: Are you directly appending the value or via any variable in your URL?

Comment: hi @GarimaGupta, should be direcly appending the value to url.
 like : http://localhost:8080/test/service/searchTest/231 2312