# navigate to file with a plus (+) in the URL

Tags: apache, url

Trying to navigate to an image within a folder that contains a plus (`+`) symbol. Folder name is `/html/images/a+b/image.jpg`

It seems to be causing issues, as I believe the browser is substituting a space (or `%2B`) for the plus sign.

Is there a way I can access that image with the current folder name? I know it is the plus sign that's the problem, because if I change the folder name and remove the plus, `/html/images/ab/image.jpg` it will load properly.

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem... what browser do you use? This problem persists in all browsers?

Comment: Think it's related to apache... it doesn't like the plus sign in the folder name.

Comment: Is it also a problem if you enter the image URL in the browser manually? Do you refer to the image in HTML, and if so, how?

Comment: @DanielRoethlisberger Yes. I can't navigate through the browser, nor can I use it in html.

Answer (score 2):

`+` is how you [encode a space character in a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20).  If you are trying to access a filename that contains a literal `+`, you'll need to encode it as `%2B`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a shot and let you know.