# How do i dynamically change the size of my iframe within a document.write

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here my code.
I also like to know why my search only take one word. for example if i type in "blue sky" it only take the word blue.

```
</script>

        document.write("<iframe src=\http://www.bing.com/search?q="  + decodeURIComponent(search) + "\"        width=\"100\%\" height=\"500\">");
        document.write("</iframe>");

         </script>
```

Comment: for multiply words check your decode URI component function, looks it does not work properly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20

Comment: so you want dynamically change height of the iframe depending on search content?

Comment: yes i would like to change the iframe depending on the search content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a class to the iframe and you can manipulate it with Javascript, JS with jQuery, CSS, etc...