# follow ajax call in debugger

Tags: html, ajax, forms, post

I'm using Chrome (and IE's) network tools in the debugger to view
what form data I'm sending by ajax calls.

This is the parsed data:

[image]

This is the source data:

[image]

The lines marked in yellow are what my question is about.
The first picture shows the correct string that I'm sending: **description +'---'**.

The second picture shows: **description%2B'+---'**, where %2B is code for a plus sign.

I'm wondering, how can there be 2 plus signs in the second picture (the actual plus and the %2B)? Furthermore, what is this second plus doing inside the quotes?

That's not the data that I'm sending. On the server side it receives correctly, but I'm just wondering, is it a bug in IE and chrome Debugger or am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing something, but it's very subtle: in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding, the space character is changed to a `+`. So the second plus is not a plus, but rather an encoded space.

For more information, see the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20) question.

Comment: Perfect answer :) just what I was looking for