# encodeURIcomponent while constructing mailto link

Tags: javascript, mailto, encodeuricomponent

When i use encodeURIComponent to encode the body as shown below, and if the body has spaces in it, the resulting link is broken and appears as follows :

http://www.sample.com/sample/explore?itemId=123&type=sample&name=name with space

```
body = "http://www.sample.com/sample/explore?itemId=123&type=sample&name=name with space"

var newLink = "mailto:?subject=" + encodeURIComponent(subject) + "&body=" + encodeURIComponent(body);

window.location = newLin
```

How can i fix it and create a valid url?

console.log shows the encoded url correctly but in outlook the link is broken. It should appear as a proper hyperlink

Comment: Have you made sure that its not because of the browser displaying the unescaped version in the address bar?

Comment: Have you tried escape instead of encodeURIComponent?

Comment: Do `console.log(newLink);` and you'll see it is encoding correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to replace `space` with `%20` in the `body` variable?

```
body = "http://www.sample.com/sample/explore?itemId=123&type=sample&name=name%20with%20space"
```

I suggest you to use [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) tool to encode *plain text* into *querystring*. If you need to pass a *newline* (`\n`), for example, use the `%0A` for newline `\n`  and `%0D` for carriage return `\r` . Look at [this](https://www.asciitable.com/) ASCII table to understand the encoding: the second column (Hx = hexadecimal ASCII representation), with a `%` as prefix, corresponds to the red character reported in the fifth column (Chr = character), that is, for example:

**space** character (fifth column, Chr, in the table) = `%20` (second column, Hx, in the table) ≅ `+` (read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1634293/2149425) answer)