# plus is getting placed instead of space while posting text on twitter

Tags: android, string, twitter

I am using the below code to post string on twitter but instead of space, plus is getting placed in my posted string. How can I resolve this problem?

```
Intent inte = new Intent(
      Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
      Uri.parse("https://mobile.twitter.com/compose/tweet?status="
        + "La Mar Cebicheria"+ "     " + sharepath));
    startActivity(inte);

    mpopup.dismiss();
```

below is the image as how my text is looking

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Uri.parse](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) method takes an encoded string which is compliant with [RFC-2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) . In this format, [space characters are encoded to plus signs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20).

To get the properly formatted URL, you should do something like:

```
URI uri = new URI("http", "https://mobile.twitter.com/compose/tweet?status="
        + "La Mar Cebicheria"+ "     " + sharepath, null);
URL url = uri.toURL();
```