# URLEncoder troubles

Tags: java, url, encoding

I've got String `Ruby On Rails`, it should be converted to `Ruby%20On%20Rails`, but `URLEncoder` says `Ruby+On+Rails`. This is my try:

```
String encoded = URLEncoder.encode("Ruby On Rails");
System.out.println(encoded);
```

Is it happening because `encode()` method is deprecated?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URLEncoder doesn't do URI encoding, it does `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which converts spaces to `+` signs.  If you want them converting to `%20` then you need something that does URI encoding instead, such as [Spring's UriUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriUtils.html#encodeQueryParam%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).