# How to use html anchor with space?

Tags: html, anchor, wikipedia, anchorpoint

**I wan't to access a wikipedia page with anchor - I'm not sure if this a 'wikipedia' or HTML related question**

Access a single word with an anchor is easy

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#History ✔

But how can I access a header with space?

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Principle of operation ✗
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Principle%20of%20operation ✗
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Principleofoperation ✗

Comment: For reference, you can right-click a link in the table of contents, and select _Copy link address_ (or whatever it's called in your browser). This way you don't have to guess what the anchor is called on each site ...

Comment: @Useless well ... shame about me. Of course you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, space is `%20`, but wikipedia uses `_`
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Principle_of_operation

Comment: and github uses dash symbol `-` aka minus

Answer (score 1):

put underscore for particular heading like 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Principle_of_operation
it will take you directly on particular heading.please check it

Comment: you can test it by clicking on the heading and retrieve the link(on url) form there !!

Comment: Please *don't* post duplicate answers. See my answer.

Comment: nicael , i didn't copy your answer. I had discovered it but mean while you had already post it here. After posting my answer i saw your one.

Answer (score 0):

It's `_` for wikipedia links, but...

A more general HTML answer is...  web developers can created named anchors (With HTML of the form: `<a name="myname">`) with whatever name they like. Different websites do different things.

If an anchor name does have a space in it, that's a bit ugly (I'm inclined to say bad web design actually), but it can be linked to by encoding the space as `%20`. Interestingly you cannot encode this as `+`, despite that working in the path and query param parts of the URL ([this answer has more detail on that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29948396/338265))

So what's actually happening on wikipedia, is that the website developers *choose* to provide named anchors corresponding to every heading on a page, and they choose to name these with the text of the heading (no surprises) except spaces are changed to underscores (which avoids ugly urls and seems like good web design).