# ASP.NET URL ending in /%20/ is not getting to application code

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

If one has a URL like this:

`https://someserver/somewebApp/%20/` ~ http exhibits the same problem.

it appears that IIS (v7.5) has a defect because control for URL evaluation does not appear to be passed to the application?

Can anyone confirm they have seen this before?
Is there a Microsoft reference to the defect (I can't find one)?

To answer the comment regarding the error received - no sub code offered (at least by fiddler):

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Comment: what is the error? are you getting HTTP 500? If yes, what's the subcode?

Comment: @Tony - added error from fiddler intercept.

Comment: You could add this to your webconfig `<httpRuntime>` `relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"`. It opens up security issues, though.

Answer (score 0):

Generally %20 represents a space in url. so your url will be like /somewebApp/ /. this might be a problem as it is not a valid url. 
You can refer following link about %20

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20
```