# How to properly encode urls with flask

Tags: flask, urlencode, werkzeug

I have a small flask app, and for some reason the parameters get only partially encoded. In particular, it looks like spaces ' ' get encoded as '+' instead of '%20' - how can I fix this?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with that encoding?  [If you're confused about the difference, here's a reference link.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1634271/1079354)

Comment: Form parameters **should** be encoded as `+`. What makes you think otherwise?