# How to select limited number of words from a textbox using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, plagiarism-detection

I have been trying to create a plagiarism webpage.It will take the input from a text box and search in Google. if found it will display the results.
Now the problem is , its searching the whole text at once but i need that to search 10 words at a time, and should search till the end in loops of 10 words.

Here is my code:

```
//Google search code
if(isset($_POST['nm'])) {
     $query = $_POST["nm"];
     $string = str_replace(' ', '%20', $_POST["nm"]);
}
$url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=".$string;
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: $query is the input from the text box. it will search query in the google and search results are displayed.What i actually need is : It should search in a 10 words loop rather than searching the whole query at once.

Comment: So explode on spaces then loop through the array for each "word". Also why do you have the `str_replace` why not use `urlencode`?

Comment: @chris85 that's what i need actually, How to do that? can you guide me.

Comment: Wait...this is suppose to be JS or PHP?...Your code is PHP

Comment: Any questions/issues with answers posted? If not and one has resolved your issue please be sure to mark it, http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it

```
if(isset($_POST['nm'])) {
    $words = explode(' ', $_POST["nm"]);
    foreach($words as $word) {
        $url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=". urlencode($word);
        //make request
    }
}
```

This splits your string on every single space then generates a URL with the string encoded.

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6118501275d95762ce9238b91261ff435da4e8cf

Functions:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Update (per every 10 words):

```
if(isset($_POST['nm'])) {
    $words = explode(' ', $_POST["nm"]);
    foreach($words as $wordcount => $word) {
        if($wordcount % 10 == 0 && !empty($wordcount)) {
             echo 'Hit 10th word, what to do?' . "\n\n";
        }
        $url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=". urlencode($word);
        echo $url . "\n";
    }
}
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7a676951da1521a4c769a8ef092227f2aabcebe1

Additional function:
Modulus Operator : http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Answer (score 0):

One way to split the string into chunks with a certain amount of words could be:

[EDIT] a shorter way would be:

```
$text = "This is some text to demonstrate the splitting of text into chunks with a defined number of words.";
$wordlimit = 10;
$words = preg_split("/\s+/",$text);  

$strings = array_chunk($words,$wordlimit);
foreach($strings AS $string){
    $url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=". urlencode(implode(" ", $string));
    echo $url."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think you have to use `+` instead of `%20`

```
if(isset($_POST['nm'])) {
     $query = implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $_POST['nm']), 0, 10));
     $string = urlencode ($query );
}
$url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=".$string;
```

Comment: `+` and `%20` both work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20