# How to send a JSON query containing spaces?

Tags: android, android-volley

I am populating my ListView with Volley Library from the Link

```
"http://192.168.***.***/allquestions/prev_ans.php/?number="+phone_number+"&&query="+query"
```

Suppose, the Json array for query "question change" is

```
[{"Name":"AAAAA","Id":"101010101","ques":"question change","Type":"class1","relatedFields":"Eduation","Name":"hshsusu","ans":"new answer 1","replyDate":"2015-09-14","replyTime":"21:05:39"}]
```

and the JSON array for query "newquestionforcrop" is

```
[{"Name":"AAAAA","Id":"101010101","ques":"question change","Type":"class1","relatedFields":"Eduation","Name":"hshsusu","ans":"new answer 1","replyDate":"2015-09-14","replyTime":"21:05:39"}]
```

The problem is, it only populate the list when my query has no space between them.

How should I resolve this?

Comment: Suggest that you use POST request instead, then put your Json in the request's body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You URL should be encoded, because spaces can't be used in it, and must be replaced by %20.

You should use something like : `query = URLEncoder.encode(query, "utf-8");`

Comment: actually,spaces are replaced by +

Comment: Well, both may be used, and it depends on the langage and the implementation. I'm pretty sure that both works the same on most of the servers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20