# Why does razor produce incorrect results with Server.UrlEncode?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, urlencode

I have the following string `LIVEWIRE TS+`

When I do the following code:

```
  <a href="/support/knowledge-base?category=@Server.UrlEncode("LIVEWIRE TS+")" class="topic-knowledge-base button">KNOWLEDGE BASE</a>
```

It produces the following query string:

`LIVEWIRE+TS%2b`

I thought a space was `%20` when encoded.

Ok, after decoding it, I got back `LIVEWIRE TS`, but not `LIVEWIRE TS+`. How can I retain the + sign?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20

Comment: + is spacebar and %20 is plus sign.

Comment: no space is '+' when encoded if you want you can check it here http://www.url-encode-decode.com/

Comment: @Sousuke - When i decode the value, I lost the + sign, I need to keep that.

Comment: The fact that `+` is used to encode a space is unrelated to your problem and your result shows that that part got decoded correctly. The complete string `LIVEWIRE+TS%2b` is supposed to decode to `LIVEWIRE TS+` though, as one answer already shows. Can you show your code that's doing the decoding?

Comment: @Sousuke `+` can sometimes be space. `%20` is space as well, but always. Only `%2b` is a URL encoding of a plus sign.

Comment: My bad, sure %20 is space and %2b is plus.

Answer (score 0):

To decode it to get the same string you have to use this code:

```
System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode("LIVEWIRE+TS%2b");
```

And it will return `LIVEWIRE TS+`.