# Prevent URL.toString() from escaping plus (+) symbols

Tags: javascript

I want to write a method that takes an array of strings and joins them with a `+` symbol, similarily to what Google does. This is my method:

```
function getQueryUrl(array) {
  let urlParamsString = array.join("+");
  const url = new URL(window.location);
  url.searchParams.set("query", urlParamsString);
  return url.toString();
}
```

But instead of getting the cleanly plus-separated URL, the URL API escapes the symbols with `%2B`. Is there any way to prevent this (apart from straight-up replacing the escaped symbols back to +)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URLSearchParams does not return the same string as found in a URL's parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45516070/urlsearchparams-does-not-return-the-same-string-as-found-in-a-urls-parameters)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better understandable with examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try unescape() function:

```
function getQueryUrl(array) {
  let urlParamsString = array.join("+");
  const url = new URL(window.location);
  url.searchParams.set("query", urlParamsString);
  return unescape(url.toString());
}
```

Comment: The `unescape()` function is deprecated. We should use `decodeURI()` or `decodeURIComponent()` instead. (read: [JavaScript unescape()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp#:~:text=The%20unescape()%20function%20is,()%20or%20decodeURIComponent()%20instead.) )

Answer (score 4):

Update:
use decodeURIComponent(url.toString());