# Why the url first parameter is not being considered in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, query-string, url-parameters, urlsearchparams

```js
const url = new URLSearchParams('https://example.com?q1=1&q2=2');
console.log(url.has('q3')) // returns false as expected
console.log(url.has('q2')) // returns true as expected
console.log(url.has('q1')) // returns false as NOT expected
```

Why it happens?

Comment: Read the documentation: [`URL`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL), [`URLSearchParams`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URLSearchParams does not return the same string as found in a URL's parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45516070/urlsearchparams-does-not-return-the-same-string-as-found-in-a-urls-parameters)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `URLSearchParams` constructor, if passed a string, expects that string to be a **query string** and not a complete URL.

`q1` doesn't appear because your first parameter is `https://example.com?q1`.

```js
const url = new URLSearchParams('https://example.com?q1=1&q2=2');
console.log([...url.entries()]);
```

Use the `URL` constructor if you want to parse a complete URL.

```js
const url = new URL('https://example.com?q1=1&q2=2');
console.log(url.searchParams.has('q3'))
console.log(url.searchParams.has('q2'))
console.log(url.searchParams.has('q1'))
```