# Kendo: values being passed as %20

Tags: javascript, json, kendo-ui, uri

```
var example = " ";

transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "geData/" + example 
                },`
```

Output:
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [getData/%20/]

I have tried var test= decodeURI(example ) also

Comment: `%20` is *space*, do your url expects an space or it should have a value instead ?

Comment: I expect a space

Comment: So it is correct, since there is no space in an URL. That is why the encoded char. Probably not your problem. That error message seems not to be from javascript also. Can you tell where it comes from ?

Comment: I am trying to find out how i can send it without the encoded char, i cant tell so far

Comment: You **can't** have space in url, it have to be a special char anyway. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1634271/1267304