# Convert "%2B" to "+" in URL querystring

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a text input within a form that uses the get method:

```
<form method="get" action="./" role="search">
  <input name="query" type="text" value="">
  <button>Go</button>
</form>
```

When the form is submitted with 'foo bar', the reloaded URL looks like this:

```
mywpsite.com/?query=foo%2Bbar
```

How can this be rendered with `+` in place of `%2B` as on Duckduckgo.com, Google and similar sites? Example:

```
mywpsite.com/?query=foo+bar
```

Comment: Str_replace? Did you try it?

Comment: @Andreas where in the form would I use it?

Comment: `echo urldecode($_GET['query'])` to `echo str_replace("%2B", "+",urldecode($_GET['query']))` or `echo str_replace(" ", "+", $_GET['query'])` because urlencode makes a space `%2B` so without urlencode you can just replace space with `+`. But that could make other url characters be messed up. But what is the point of all this in the first place?

Comment: The string gets url-encoded when you submit the form, and cannot be changed in the url itself.

Comment: @Qirel how do sites like duckduckgo.com achieve it?

Comment: It's indeed browser behaviour and Firefox behaves as expected. What browser are you testing this with ? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271#answer-1634293) might be relevant.

Comment: @msg in Safari and Chrome

Answer (score 0):

it's not a good solution, but i suppose this would work:

```
if(false!==stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"%2B")){
    http_response_code(307);
    header("Location: ".strtr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],array('%2b'=>'+','%2B'=>'+')));
    die();
}
```

- the code must run before the response body has been generated/sent.

this code checks if the request url contains "%2b", and if it does,
   tell the browser to try the request again at the url with "%2b"
   converted to "+".

Comment: I'm getting `A non-numeric value encountered` error on the 3rd line

Comment: @user2726041 sorry, i used `+` to concatenate the string instead of `.`, `+` is how to do it in javascript, `.` is how to do it in PHP, i got them mixed. code updated, try again ^^

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting an ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS for some reason now

Comment: @user2726041 browser?

Comment: in Chrome latest version

Comment: @user2726041 oh i think i got it, might have been a CaSe SeNsItIvItY problem, try again, updated the code to be case-insensitive

Comment: Great thanks, working now. But now spaces are showing up as '%20'

Comment: Strange.. It seems to ignore that and still shows as %20

Comment: @user2726041 %20 or %2B ? either way, try this? https://paste.debian.net/plain/1049233

Comment: @user2726041 what if you change 307 to 302  for http_response_code() ?

Comment: Yes, still TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error... the URL is now showing pluses though :)

Comment: @user2726041 and 303?

Comment: Still TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS for 303

Comment: @user2726041 do you have a live url where i can see it for myself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182633/discussion-between-user2726041-and-hanshenrik).