# How to properly create HTML links in PHP?

Tags: php, url

This question is about the proper use of [rawurlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php), [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) & [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Until now my standard way of creating HTML link in vanilla PHP was this:

```
$qs = [
    'foo' => 'foo~bar',
    'bar' => 'bar foo',
];
echo '<a href="?' . http_build_query($qs) . '">Link</a>';
```

Recently I have learned that this is not 100% correct. Here are few issues:

- `http_build_query` uses by default **PHP_QUERY_RFC1738** instead of **PHP_QUERY_RFC3986**. RFC3986 is the standard and superseded RFC1738 which in PHP is only kept for legacy use.
- While the "special" HTML characters in the key and value part will be encoded to the percent-encoded representation, the argument separator will be an ampersand. In most sane situations this would not be a problem, but sometimes your key name might be `quot;` and then your link will become invalid:

  ```
  $qs = [
      'a' => 'a',
      'quot;' => 'bar',
  ];
  echo '<a href="?' . http_build_query($qs) . '">Link</a>';
  ```

  The code above will generate this link: `?a=a"%3B=bar`!
  IMO this implies that the function `http_build_query` needs to be called context-aware with the 3-rd argument `&amp;` when in HTML, and with just `&` when in `header('Location: ...');`. Another option would be to pass it through `htmlspecialchars` before displaying in HTML.
- PHP manual for [`urlencode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) (*which should be deprecated long time ago IMO*) suggests to encode only the value part of query string and then pass the whole query string through `htmlentities` before displaying in HTML. This looks very incorrect to me; the key part could still contain forbidden URL characters.

  ```
  $query_string = 'foo=' . urlencode($foo) . '&bar=' . urlencode($bar);
  echo '<a href="mycgi?' . htmlentities($query_string) . '">';
  ```

My conclusion is to do something along this lines:

```
$qs = [
    'a' => 'a',
    'quot;' => 'bar foo',
];
echo '<a href="?' . http_build_query($qs, null, '&amp;', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986) . '">Link</a>';
```

What is the recommended way to create HTML links in PHP? Is there an easier way than what I came up with? Have I missed any crucial points?

Comment: This question might be better off on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I disagree. I am not asking for a review, I am looking for an answer how to properly create links. Code review serves a different purpose.

Comment: `The code above will generate this link: ?a=a"%3B=bar!` Not for me. I get `<a href="?a=a&quot%3B=bar">Link</a>` from your example, which appears to work fine.

Comment: @ceejayoz Hover over, or click it...

Comment: I did it in Tinker, so it's not clickable. If browsers don't handle it correctly, blame them, or (my preference) the idiot developer who decided `quot;` was a good name for a GET parameter. PHP isn't messing up here - run your `http_build_query` through `htmlspecialchars`. A good framework will do this automatically, like Laravel's `{{ }}`.

Comment: @ceejayoz If I am not mistaken you are referring to [this Twig filter](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/072214b6e31fe7847424f43de5e8c0727511b2ab/src/Extension/CoreExtension.php#L598) which is just a wrapper for `http_build_query($url, '', '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);`

Comment: No, I'm referring to Laravel's Blade templating language, where `{{ }}` is a wrapper that passes through `htmlspecialchars` for safe output to HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to dynamically build HTML links with query string?

If you need to create query string to be used in HTML link (e.g. `<a href="index.php?param1='.$value.'">Link</a>`) then you should use [`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).
This function accepts 4 parameters, with the first one being an array/object of query data. For the most part the other 3 parameters are irrelevant.

```
$qs = [
    'a' => 'a',
    'quot;' => 'bar foo',
];
echo '<a href="?' . http_build_query($qs) . '">Link</a>';
```

However, **you should still pass the output of the function through [`htmlspecialchars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)** to encode the `&` correctly. *"A good framework will do this automatically, like Laravel's {{ }}"*

```
echo '<a href="?' . htmlspecialchars(http_build_query($qs)) . '">Link</a>';
```

Alternatively you can pass the third argument to `http_build_query` as `'&amp;'`, leaving the second one `null`. This will use `&amp;` instead of `&` which is what `htmlspecialchars` would do.

**About spaces**.
For use in form data (i.e. query strings) the space [should be encoded as `+` and in any other place it should be encoded as `%20`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29948396/1839439) e.g. `new%20page.php?my+field=my+val`. This is to ensure backwards comparability with all browsers. You can use the newer RFC3986 which will encode the spaces as `%20` and it will work in all common browsers as well as be up to date with modern standards.

```
echo '<a href="?' . http_build_query($qs, null, '&amp;', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986) . '">Link</a>';
```

---

#### `rawurlencode`  vs `urlencode`

For any part of URL before `?` you should use [`rawurlencode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php). For example:

```
$subdir = rawurlencode('blue+light blue');
echo '<a href="'.$subdir.'/index.php">rawurlencode</a>';
```

If in the above example you used `urlencode` the link would be broken. `urlencode` has very limited use and should be avoided.

Do not pass whole URL through `rawurlencode`. Separators `/` and other special characters in URL should not be encoded if they are to fulfil their function.

---

*Footnote*

There is no general agreement on the best practices for using `http_build_query`, other than the fact it should be passed through `htmlspecialchars` just like any other output in HTML context.

[Laravel](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/024783a3328c1e666390307e6704e64f256cb327/src/Illuminate/Support/Arr.php#L592) uses `http_build_query($array, null, '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986)`

[CodeIgniter](https://github.com/codeigniter4/framework/blob/4fc8c8549ea009c7489183e951d7da7f8a7dcd39/system/HTTP/URI.php#L826) uses `http_build_query($query)`

[Symfony](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2c9a1960a164a857cd551881b580266bc77bdafa/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Generator/UrlGenerator.php#L291) uses `http_build_query($extra, '', '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986)`

[Slim](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/fe39e6ef0e669a0003123247e9a9da73f10fef92/Slim/Router.php#L389) uses `http_build_query($queryParams)`

[CakePHP](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/5abb52489c3c98631c21a740ca9024c579c77b1e/src/Http/Client.php#L470) uses `http_build_query($query)`

[Twig](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/1190d3d42031d0484f421bb5dc2e8759e786caa4/src/Extension/CoreExtension.php#L608) uses `http_build_query($url, '', '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986)`