# I need to encode a URL in a table field from PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, url

I need to encode some data from an SQL database into a URL, but I cannot work out how to do it.

I have tried putting urlencode() in different places and storing them in variables.

```html
Print "<td><a href =" .$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. "?id=" . $info['id'] ." &name=" . $info['Name'] . "&author=" . $info['Author'] ."&subject=" .
$info['Subject'] . "&series=" . @$info['Series'] . "&mode=edit>Edit</a></td>";
```

Comment: no, that just spits out ```http://localhost:8080/AT1.php?id=11```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly create HTML links in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55366208/how-to-properly-create-html-links-in-php)

Comment: You need to observe the difference between single and double quotes.  To get you started:  `print '<td><a href="'.$SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'"?id=`

Answer (score 0):

Embed PHP Tags properly in a HTML Hyperlink , followed by you Values example

?id=&name=">