# Adding PHP variables to HTML href

Tags: php, html

I need to add two variables to my url to make it more secure. But I can't add php in my href.

this is the code:

```
<php
$token =1;
$email =2;
$body='
<body>
<p>Use the link below to reset your password.</p><br>
<a href="http://localhost/wwi/view/pw_reset.php?token=<?php echo $token?>&email=<?php echo $email?>">Click here</a>
</body>';
```

but the result I get now is:

`http://localhost/wwi/view/pw_reset.php?token=echo$token&email=echo$email`

instead of what I need which is:

`http://localhost/wwi/view/pw_reset.php?token=1&email=2`

It needs to be in the variable `$body` because this is used to send an email with `phpmailer`.

Comment: It looks like you have missed out the semi collen at the end of the php echo statement. I have put the corrected code in the answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly create HTML links in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55366208/how-to-properly-create-html-links-in-php)

Comment: @Dharman, it's self-promotion? :D OP doesn't ask `how to make it properly`, he faced an issue. Issue was in tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should like

`<php` should be `<?php`

Because you are already in **php** blog, then do not use again `<?php..`

```
$token =1;
$email =2;
$body='
<body>
<p>Use the link below to reset your password.</p><br>
<a href="http://localhost/wwi/view/pw_reset.php?token='.$token.'&email='.$email.'">Click here</a>
</body>';
```

Comment: This is not recommended for URLs. You should use http_build_query.

Comment: yeah right @Dharman, but here i just fix error in existing code only.

Answer (score 0):

You've forgot `?` at the beginning in `<php` -> should be `<?php`

If you're creating a string then use concatenation:

```
$body= 'text'.$email.'text'.$token.'text';
```

`<?php echo ?>` could be used if prev `<?php` was closed by `?>`. It happens often inside HTML document. In case of using it inside `<?php ?>` like `<?php <?php ?>` it will raise an error.

Comment: They're building URL and not a string. It's different.

Comment: @Dharman, OP did it like a string. So, if you wanna rewrite his project - contact him.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use below code, it will works for you.

```
<?php

 $token =1;
 $email =2;
 $body='
 <body>
 <p>Use the link below to reset your password.</p><br>
 <a href="http://localhost/wwi/view/pw_reset.php?token='.$token.'&email='.$email.'" > Click here </a>
 </body>';
```

Comment: Unexplained duplicate

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't saw it

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$token =1;
$email =2;
$body='
<body>
    <p>Use the link below to reset your password.</p><br>
    <a href="http://localhost/wwi/view/pw_reset.php?token='. $token'. '&email='. $email">Click here</a>
</body>';
```

Comment: Why should I try this?

Comment: You did. In the answer. Please provide some explanation.