# php deal with & as part of a string in URL

Tags: php, urlencode, ampersand

I'm trying to parse a string passed from one page to another in PHP ($_GET), this string has an "&" in it like this:

> Help & Support

The name is url encoded, so the & turns into %26.

```
<a href="http://test.com/category/Help+%26+Support">Help &amp; Support</a>
```

My problem is when a user clicks a link, the next page picks up the string as "Help " and seems to just stop where the %26 is?

I know I'm not supposed to decode it, since $_GET is done automatically.

What am I missing to get the whole string?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the `.htaccess` content to your question.

Comment: @Progman that was it, brill thank you!

Comment: Please note that space should be encoded as `%20` and not as `+`. See my earlier question https://stackoverflow.com/q/55366208/1839439