# Convert html url into uri module ansible

Tags: ansible, rally

I am looking to convert the html url into ansible uri module, when i load the url in browser it gives results, but from uri module i am getting errors

My URL:- 
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/user?query=(FirstName = test1)&fetch=true

Ansible uri module:-

```
      uri:
        url: https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/user?query=(FirstName = "test1")&fetch=true
        user: myusername
        password: mypass
        force_basic_auth: yes
        follow_redirects: all
        return_content: yes
        method: GET
      register: get_data
    - debug: var=get_data
```

I am getting this error:-

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"cache_control": "no-cache", "cf_ray": "4dd5a65fea0cba46-ATL", "changed": false, "connection": "close", "content": "<html><body><h1>400 Bad request</h1>\nYour browser sent an invalid request.\n</body></html>\n", "content_type": "text/html", "date": "Mon, 27 May 2019 05:39:42 GMT",
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that your URL contains spaces (), which aren't valid URL characters. If I run your code against a sample web server, I see the following error after the `uri` module has successfully negotiated an SSL connection:

> An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: http.client.InvalidURL: URL can't contain control characters. '/slm/webservic
>   e/v2.0/user?query=(FirstName = "test1")&fetch=true' (found at least ' ')
>   fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "content": "", "elapsed": 0, "msg": "Status code was -1 and not [200]: An unknown error occurred: URL can't contain control 
>   characters. '/slm/webservice/v2.0/user?query=(FirstName = \"test1\")&fetch=true' (found at least ' ')", "redirected": false, "status": -1, "url": "https://localhost:8080/slm/
>   webservice/v2.0/user?query=(FirstName = \"test1\")&fetch=true"}

Spaces in a URL should be [encoded as `+` or as `%20`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20), so you could write your URL like this:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/user?query=(FirstName+=+"test1")&fetch=true
```

Or like this:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/user?query=(FirstName%20=%20"test1")&fetch=true
```

Or, if the query is valid without spaces, just write:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/user?query=(FirstName="test1")&fetch=true
```