# How to access air quality API through R?

Tags: r, api, httr

Trying to access [AirQuality API](https://api-docs.airvisual.com/?version=latest), very new to this and do not see simple R tutorials.

Got my username and password.

And I am interested to get LA data as a sample

```
api.airvisual.com/v2/city?city=Los Angeles&state=California&country=USA&key={{KEY}}
```

My credentials

**username <- "My new free api key"** *(that is how they give it)*

**password <- "KEY"**

Then I try to use some code from tutorials

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

url <- "api.airvisual.com/v2/city?city=Los Angeles&state=California&country=USA&key={{KEY}}"

endpoint <- "city"

some_data <- GET(url, endpoint)
```

**It gives me an error**

**Error in if (is_http) { : argument is of length zero**

Their parameters are

Parameters

**city:** city's English name, can be found using the respective listing endpoint.

**state:** state's English name, can be found using the respective listing endpoint.

**country:** country's English name, can be found using the respective listing endpoint.

I am sure it is something super simple, but I never did it before, so I stumbled. Please advise.

**UPD.**

When I use

```
url <- "api.airvisual.com/v2/city?city=Los%20Angeles&state=California&country=USA&key={{KEY}}"
```

with %20 instead of space, it gives me an error

**Error in UseMethod("as.request") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.request' applied to an object of class "character"**

Comment: what is endpoint?

Comment: the space in the URL might give you problems; it may need to be encoded into `%20` - [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1634271/5977215)

Comment: @Alex, city is the endpoint I believe

Comment: @SymbolixAU, interesting. I am copying from the tutorial. There is a space there.

Comment: It's not in the example request they give `curl --location --request GET "api.airvisual.com/v2/city?city=Los%20Angeles&state=California&country=USA&key={{YOUR_API_KEY}}"` - it's been encoded to `%20`

Comment: @SymbolixAU, ok I see, but on the left side they do not give it. But still does not work, I tried with a new link. Please see the error.

Comment: what if you just use `GET( url )` ?

Comment: @SymbolixAU, Error in if (is_http) { : argument is of length zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to specify endpoint. You can directly use GET as follows:

```
require(httr)
response = GET("https://api.airvisual.com/v2/city?city=Los%20Angeles&state=California&country=USA&key={{my_private_key}}")
```

If you further need to access data from the response, the code would be:

```
data = content(response)
```

`data` is a list which looks like:

```
$status
[1] "success"

$data
$data$city
[1] "Los Angeles"

$data$state
[1] "California"

$data$country
[1] "USA"

$data$location
$data$location$type
[1] "Point"

$data$location$coordinates
$data$location$coordinates[[1]]
[1] -118.2417

$data$location$coordinates[[2]]
[1] 34.0669



$data$current
$data$current$weather
$data$current$weather$ts
[1] "2019-10-23T07:00:00.000Z"

$data$current$weather$tp
[1] 20

$data$current$weather$pr
[1] 1014

$data$current$weather$hu
[1] 52

$data$current$weather$ws
[1] 0.78

$data$current$weather$wd
[1] 345

$data$current$weather$ic
[1] "01n"


$data$current$pollution
$data$current$pollution$ts
[1] "2019-10-23T07:00:00.000Z"

$data$current$pollution$aqius
[1] 37

$data$current$pollution$mainus
[1] "p1"

$data$current$pollution$aqicn
[1] 41

$data$current$pollution$maincn
[1] "p1"
```

Let me know if this works.

P.S. I even tried for Los Angeles using %20 instead of the space and it works.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please share the FULL code from your IDE? I am still struggling. Maybe I am missing something simple. Please update your answer a bit. With password etc.

Comment: @Oleksiy I have added the full code from my console and the output too. If you tell me what error you are getting, I will be able to debug.

Comment: library(httr)
response <- GET("api.airvisual.com/v2/city?city=Mumbai&state=Maharashtra&country=India&key={MYKEY}")  gives me an error Error in if (is_http) { : argument is of length zero.

Comment: Add 'https://' in the beginning of the URL. Just to be safe, encode your key as ```URLencode(MYKEY)``` where MYKEY is a string object containing your key.

Comment: Ok, did some progress

Comment: $status
[1] "fail"

$data
$data$message
[1] "incorrect_api_key"

Comment: Are you sure the api key is correct? If you are 100% sure, then remove the URLencode part.

Comment: Well, I just copy-pasting from the dashboard.

Comment: Can you please give the specific code with ``URLencode``. Maybe the error is there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201307/discussion-between-makeshift-programmer-and-oleksiy).

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the scheme as part of the URL:

```
library(httr)
GET("https://api.airvisual.com/....")
     ^^^^^^^^
```