# How to open Sygic maps using intent?

Tags: java, android, sygic

I am trying to search for an place in the sygic app using

```
  String str = "com.sygic.aura://search|Gas%Station";
  startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(str)));
```

as intended by the [documentation](https://www.sygic.com/developers/professional-navigation-sdk/android/api-examples/custom-url). However the code only opens the app, and the search bar is empty. It doesn't search for anything.

What am I doing wrong? I have spent hours trying to look for and figure out a solution.

Comment: if you want to search for `Gas Station` I think you should write like `Gas%20Station` not `Gas%Station`

Comment: @dinkar_kumar tried already. did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Few trials you could make, if you havent done so, from my research on sygic documentation and google( I have not used the sygic app)

1. Try using + sign for space, like Gas+Station in your search string, if %20 is not solving the issue.
   [URL encoding the space character: + or %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20)
2. Since the doucmentation mentions to follow encoding, try rewriting Url as per documnentation example
   "
   Please note that for majority of uses the parameter string needs to be URL-encoded (so called percent encoding).
   It normally relates to the following characters: "#%<>[]^`{|} and the SPACE. For exact rules check the documentation on Encoding
   Example: Instead of com.sygic.aura://route_download|http://dat.my.com/my route.sif
   use com.sygic.aura://route_download%7Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdata.my.com%2Fmy%20route.sif"
3. Checkout this example provided in documentation. Maybe you want to split "Gas Station" into 2 strings

   String lon = "15.06591";
   String lat = "47.73341";
   String type = "drive";
   String str = "com.sygic.aura://coordinate|" + lon + "|" + lat + "|" + type;
   startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(str)));