# Python netsuite request parameters

Tags: python, python-requests, netsuite

I have the following base URL

```
https://ACCOUNT_ID.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/salesOrder
```

Works fine to give me all the sales orders.
However, when I add the following query params

```
?q=createdDate AFTER "01/01/2022"
```

It says invalid URL, no schema supplied.
Works fine in postman though.

I tried having that query param exactly in the url like so;

```
https://ACCOUNT_ID.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/salesOrder?q=createdDate AFTER "01/01/2022"
```

Also tried having it as a params in requests, but this gives me an auth token error.

```
headers = {token_info,private_keys}
params = {'createdDate': 'AFTER "01/01/2022"'}
payload = {}

requests.request(HTTP_METHOD, BASE_URL, params=params, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

Wondering what else I could try.

Comment: Please, show us the values of the variables.

Comment: Updated. @radekholy24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble here is the special characters in the query parameter. They need to be properly encoded. Here is a discussion on how to encode space characters: [URL encoding the space character: + or %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1634271/542196) The `/` characters need to be encoded as `%2F` sequences and `"` as `%22`.

I have done a little experiment with the `requests` library and it seems that it expects `url` arguments to be properly encoded already:

```py
>>> BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8000?q=createdDate AFTER "01/01/2022"'
>>> params = None
>>> requests.request(HTTP_METHOD, BASE_URL, params=params, headers=headers, data=payload)
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2022 07:14:25] "GET /?q=createdDate%20AFTER%20%2201/01/2022%22 HTTP/1.1" 200 100
```

As you can see, for some reason, it encodes the space character as a `%20` sequence, whilst you need it to be encoded as a `+` character, and the `/` character is not encoded at all.

In order to fix that you would have to provide it the following `BASE_URL`:

```py
>>> BASE_URL = 'https://ACCOUNT_ID.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/salesOrder?q=createdDate+AFTER+%2201%2F01%2F2022%22'
>>> requests.request(HTTP_METHOD, BASE_URL, params=params, headers=headers, data=payload)
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2022 07:40:52] "GET /?q=createdDate+AFTER+%2201%2F01%2F2022%22 HTTP/1.1" 200 100
```

There are some libraries available that can properly encode the URL for you, but as you have already found out, `requests` can do that as well (and Postman too). All you need is to pass the query parameters as a `params` argument.

But there is a little mistake in your code snippet. You pass a query parameter with a key `createdDate` and a value `AFTER "01/01/2022"`:

```py
>>> BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8000'
>>> params = {'createdDate': 'AFTER "01/01/2022"'}
>>> requests.request(HTTP_METHOD, BASE_URL, params=params, headers=headers, data=payload)
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2022 07:48:27] "GET /?createdDate=AFTER+%2201%2F01%2F2022%22 HTTP/1.1" 200 100
```

Notice the missing `q=` there. You probably need to pass a query parameter with a key `q` and a value `createdDate AFTER "01/01/2022"`:

```py
>>> BASE_URL = 'https://ACCOUNT_ID.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/salesOrder'
>>> params = {'q': 'createdDate AFTER "01/01/2022"'}
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2022 07:50:20] "GET /?q=createdDate+AFTER+%2201%2F01%2F2022%22 HTTP/1.1" 200 100
```

Comment: So I encode the base URL when I make the auth header, and then tried the params with 'q' as well.  In this case it says token_rejected. Now I'm wondering if I have to pass the whole url to the auth header logic.

Comment: This is what my url ends up being;
`https://ACCOUNT_ID.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/salesOrder?q=createdDate+AFTER+%2201%2F01%2F2022%22`

Comment: There might be multiple reasons for token rejection. Maybe it has expired. Try to generate a new one.

Comment: Says I got an InvalidSignature. Wondering if I need to pass the query params as well when generating my OauthHeader. Right now it just has the usual params; nonce, keys, timestamp, etc.

Comment: I recommend you to use the Requests-Oauthlib library that can sign the requests for you: https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth1_workflow.html

Comment: That worked. Now I'm trying to find an async requests lib for oauth1.

Comment: Is there anywhere that specifies the filters than can be used for a given field?  I'm attemtping something similar using email in customer endpoint and am only able to use the "IS" keyword