# When using router.query, it removes some characters, but in the url it is still there

Tags: reactjs, next.js

This is how I use router.query to get hold of the token that I need so that the user can update one's password. But when I e.g. print it to my hidden, it removes e.g. + and / etc.

I have tried to use encodeURIComponent to be able to solve the problem but it seems that it does not help in any way.

Token in url: CfDJ8Pf5H7I0LCJKuxB2jm5JU0EGFK7KC45kBnwAkPgbAO2+kPijFxxb5CW6wyE/ft74if6V5ouwrHE8wK8Vz2ZTlc0s82XwwC9rZD4CvA5UQnv9eyL0UxdCqNEVjlusntVTn4d+41nLwlADsSqhLYajkRHwSHx8DhvJZa9OBGX9iYpR2EXnBOMa1EZcvvKDhEX+9+pgOtW8shPAo4p+F5nG0C+qnK4s5u/rO5vgA7SFhEkWS

When I get it into the content of the page, it looks like this. After it is displayed on the page.

CfDJ8Pf5H7I0LCJKuxB2jm5JU0EGFK7KC45kBnwAkPgbAO2 kPijFxxb5CW6wyE/ft74if6V5ouwrHE8wK8Vz2ZTlc0s82XwwC9rZD4CvA5UQnv9eyL0UxdCqNEVjlusntVTn4d 41nLwlADsSqhLYajkRHwSHx8DhvJZa9OBGX9iYpR2EXnBOMa1EZcvvKDhEX 9 pgOtW8shPAo4p F5nG0C qnK4s5u/rO5vgA7SFhEkWS

[image]

I have tried to do this:
`encodeURIComponent(String(router.query["token"]))`

And i have try

`router.query["token"]`

How can it be that you change the sign from + to between spaces or something completely different.

Comment: `...Tn4d 41nL...` there is space between `d` and `4` so you will see `space` as `%20` because browser encodes the url. So you can decode the string before printing on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can `decode` the `encodded` string before printing on the page.

```js
const encoddedUri = encodeURI("https://example.com/asdasd asdasd");
console.log(`encoded URI: ${encoddedUri}`);
console.log(`Decoded URI: ${decodeURI(encoddedUri)}`);
```

Comment: Okay, but it still doesn't make sense that it says + in relation while it still doesn't appear that I can get it on the page with what it says.

Comment: I think it may have something to do with xss attack.

Comment: See this question and its answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20