# How can I put link in caption in pdf output of Rmarkdown

Tags: pdf, r-markdown, bookdown, rticles

I am trying to convert my html output to pdf output in rmarkdown using the `rticles` package. I changed a lot of things in the `.Rmd` file and everything worked except this one thing on which I am stuck. I have a table in the Rmarkdown file which has a caption that has a link to a website as a footnote. That chunk is not working and I am getting an error. I have already tried getting the text reference in the `caption` but that also didn't work for me (I guess because I'm not using `bookdown`) Here is the code chunk:

```
X1=inflation_data$exp[!is.na(inflation_data$exp)&inflation_data$date<="2018-11-02"]-100
X2=inflation_data$exp[!is.na(inflation_data$exp)&inflation_data$date>="2019-01-01"]-100
Y1=inflation_data$inf_yy[inflation_data$date<="2018-11-02"]
Y2=inflation_data$inf_yy[inflation_data$date>="2019-01-01"]
df1<-DTW(X1,Y1)%>%setNames(c('x','Fixed ER regime'))
df2<-DTW(X2,Y2)%>%setNames(c('x','Managed ER regime'))
list_df=list(df1,df2)
df1122 <- list_df %>% reduce(inner_join, by='x')
colnames(df1122)[1]=''
knitr::kable(df1122,digits = 2, caption = 'Pan has been folRate regfixed) togram. Ogram was making ER flnto the IMF program.^[https://www.imf.org/05/12/pr19157-IF-Rhes-Sff-Lel-Ant-on-Emic-Poies-wh-Wn-for-a-Thee-Ye-EF]')%>%kable_classic("striped",font_size=10)%>%row_spec(0,bold=T)
```

And I am getting the following error:

> ! Missing $ inserted. 
> $ l.621 ...cies-with-Pakistan-for a-Three-Year-EFF]}
>
> Try to find the following text in elsevier.Rmd:
> ...cies-with-Pakistan-for a-Three-Year-EFF]}
>
> You may need to add $ $ around a certain inline R expression `r`  in
> elsevier.Rmd (see the above hint). See
> https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/385 for more info. Error:
> LaTeX failed to compile elsevier.tex. See
> https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See
> elsevier.log for more info. Execution halted

If I remove `^[https://www.imf.org/05/12/pr19157-IF-Rhes-Sff-Lel-Ant-on-Emic-Poies-wh-Wn-for-a-Thee-Ye-EF]` from my code it works fine without any error.

Also, the YAML part:

```
---
title: "My title"
author:
  - name: My name            
    email: my.name@google.com        
    affiliation: My Department, My Company        
    correspondingauthor: true
    footnote: 1
address:
  - code: My department   
    organization: My organization
    addressline: 1 my adress
    city: My city   
    state: My state
    postcode: 14000
    country: My country
footnote:
  - code: 1
    text: "This is the first author footnote."
abstract: |
  This is my long abstract. This is my long abstract. This is my long abstract. This is my long abstract. This is my long abstract. This is my long abstract. This is my long abstract. This is my long abstract. This is my long abstract. This is my long abstract. This is my long abstract. 
keywords: 
  - keyword1
  - keyword2
  - keyword3
journal: "An awesome journal"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
classoption: preprint, 3p, authoryear
bibliography: references.bib
linenumbers: false
numbersections: true
# Use a CSL with `citatssssssssssssssssssssssion_package = "default"`
# csl: https://www.zotero.org/styles/elsevier-harvard
output: 
  rticles::elsevier_article:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    keep_tex: true
    citation_package: natbib
fontsize: 12pt
---
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to provide a small reproducible example of your rmd file. With the one I made below I am not able to reproduce the error.

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
head(mtcars) |> 
    knitr::kable(caption = 'Pan has been folRate regfixed) togram. Ogram was making ER flnto the IMF program.^[https://www.imf.org/05/12/pr19157-IF-Rhes-Sff-Lel-Ant-on-Emic-Poies-wh-Wn-for a-Thee-Ye-EF]')
```
````

This makes me think is not an Rmarkdown issue. My guess would be on LaTeX having problems with either the `^` symbol or the space you have in the url:

```
Wn-for a-Thee-Ye-EF]
      ^
      ^
     here
```

Updating your LaTeX parser might help. Also, you could encode your space as `%20` following this: [URL encoding the space character: + or %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20)

Comment: This space you're referring to is a typo on my part. thanks for pointing out. I think the problem is with the mixing of `rticles` package and latex. I needed my output in a particular format and `rticles` does the job. I've edited my question with my YAML and corrected typo. Thanks!