# Regular Expression to remove &quot; &#39; from a string in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, substring

I am fetching my result from a RSS feed using following code:

```
try:  
desc = item.xpath('description')[0].text
if date is not None:
    desc =date +"\n"+"\n"+desc
except:
    desc = None
```

But sometimes the description contains  few unicode html charecters in feed as below:

> The text from XML looks like " and with ' and other &...; stuff

While displaying the content I do not want them to be displayed. Is there any regular expression to remove the HTML tags.

Comment: The XML parser should be converting these, eg. `etree.XML("<a>&quot;hi&#39;</a>").xpath('/a')[0].text` gives `'"hi\''`

Comment: Please show us the XML that you are trying to parse.

Answer (score 1):

I used something called "Unescaping XML", don't know if it's helpfull to you.

see : http://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingXml

```
from xml.sax.saxutils import unescape

unescape("&lt; &amp; &gt;")

'< & >'




unescape("&apos; &quot;", {"&apos;": "'", "&quot;": '"'})

'\' "'
```

**edit**

Just saw this, may be interresting. (Not tested) : [unescape with urllib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780334/unescape-python-strings-from-http)

Comment: @a'r  : sorry, I missed your first comment while answering; you were fist.

Comment: Sorry but I can not use third partie libraries as this will run in a embeded software ssytem

Comment: @Subhen : I just discovered another way : see first answer to this SO question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780334/unescape-python-strings-from-http but I did not try it.